# Do we need to divide the dataset to testing and training?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

My apologies for such a stupid question in advance! I thought that we need to divide data set to training and testing in svm and then using training set in order to find the model. Then check the accuracy of this model using testing set. 
In libsvm dataset "http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/multiclass.html" some data sets have the training and the testing and the others do not have the training and the testing therefore according to the libsvm guide in libsvm website, the ralated codes are different. For example in svmguide2 dataset there is not specified  testing set. So how we can test the accuracy of model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two important aspects here, first is the fact that you need to create such spliutting by yourself.

The second thing is that just splitting the set into two parts is rather not enough, as you can still find  the completely useless model, which for this one, particular split will yield good results. This is where concepts/strategies like cross-validation comes into play. In the CV setting you split your data into K equal-size chunks (where k is taken from interval [1,n] where n is the size of data) and you test k-times your model on each chunk, while training it on the rest. This way, from the limited set of examples, you can generate k distinctive test cases, each with non overlapping training and test subsets. In particular setting k=n you test so called "leave one out" scenario, which is often refered in the theoretical research. The most common choices of k are 10,5 or 3.

Answer (score -1):

You have to divide the whole data by yourself. I would actually recommend to have more than two sets. Once you are done with training and testing, it is helpful to have an extra set to check that you are not biased by the previous train-test-retrain iteration.

Also if you were going to use cross-validation to find your parameters you would need more datasets.